# Difference between objective and best value in Optuna

Tags: optuna

I'm new to Optuna and I wonder how to read this generated plot:

[image: img]

First, I wonder why I can see only two objective values and what they do represent?
Next, I wonder about the meaning best value (compared to objective values).

From my assumption I'd have expected that they fall into each other at those points?

Comment: objective value includes the values of the objective from all trials (blue dots), and it can change non-monotonically. Best value changes only when one of the blue dots beats the record, so it updates only sometimes, and changes monotonically.

Comment: @level1807 Got it, thank you! So, when I can't see more than those blue dots, this means, they fall in place with red ones, right?

Comment: yeah the first red dot after a jump of the red line coincides with a blue dot